# Laravel Excel export not including float values of 0.00

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am exporting to excel using "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1", but when I export, columns with values 0 or 0.0 are ignored and the cell is left empty.
sample code:

```
public function array(): array
{
    return $this->data;
}

public function columnFormats(): array
{
    return [
        'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
        'E' => '0.00',
        'F' => '0.00',
        'G' => '0.00'
    ];
}

public function map($rows): array
{
    return [
        $rows['employeeNumber'],
        $rows['basicSalary'],
        $rows['totalAllowance'],
        $rows['grossSalary']
    ];
}
```

when values for the columns are 0 or 0.00, nothing is inserted in the cell.
[image]

Comment: try with this. number_format((float)$value, 2, '.', '');

Comment: it is working in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly try with this

```
number_format((float)$value, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much, that works perfectly.

Comment: this not works if number of digit is zero. Every zero is treated as null

Answer (score 6):

You can use `WithStrictNullComparison` (as @Sirapat already said)

```
class YourExport implements WithStrictNullComparison
```

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#strict-null-comparisons

Or you can change the `excel.php` config file:

```
'strict_null_comparison' => true // New format
'strictNullComparison' => true   // Old format
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/have-0-instead-of-null-or-empty-cell-in-laravel-excel-appendrows

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WithStrictNullComparison`

Ex. `YourExportClass implements WithStrictNullComparison`

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#strict-null-comparisons